# while starting a docker container I have to execute a script inside docker container

Tags: docker, docker-container

while starting a docker container I have to execute a script inside docker container. Can I do it using docker run command or docker start command mentioning the path in docker? I know I have to use CMD in docker file but dockerfile is not present

Comment: have you tried docker exec -it mycontainer /bin/bash -c "commands"?

Comment: @EdcelCabreraVista  docker exec command can be used once the container is running.  Anyway i found the solution docker run --name TEST -d <imageID> sh -c " CMD "

in CMD section you can give the path of shell script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
docker run -it <image-name> bash "command-to-execute"
```

Answer (score 0):

To enter a running Docker container (get a Bash prompt inside the container), please run the following:

`docker container exec -it <container_id> /bin/bash`

You can get the **container_id** by listing running Docker containers with:

`docker container ps -a` or `docker ps -a`

Answer (score 0):

docker run --name TEST -d image sh -c " CMD "

in CMD section you can give the path of shell script